# Using differential equation mixing problem for measuring combustion gasses

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to measure the concentration of carbon monoxide as the result of combustion as a factor of time in an enclosed space, with a relief valve (e.g., without incoming flow, no gas will flow out). I was thinking of basing the equation on a mixing problem, but I have no idea how to set it up.

The tank would have a volume of $V$ cubic feet completely filled with pure "clean air", and combustion byproducts would flow in at a rate of $r$ cubic feet/minute. The clean air and the byproduct gasses have no components in common, and due to finite amounts of fuel, only $F$ cubic feet of gasses will be produced, after which all flow will stop.

I'm running into a problem when I try to set up the incoming concentration of the flow, because I have $C'(t) = r - \frac{rC(t)}{V}$, which ends up as $C(t) + C'(t) = V$, if I'm doing my math correctly. But looking at this, it seems that the flow rate has no bearing on the concentration over time, which I logically know not to be true.

Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Also, I should note that I know the composition of carbon monoxide to the other gasses in the byproduct, so I'm leaving that out of the equation for simplicity, since it stays constant.

Comment: What is the reaction equation?

Comment: C_3H_8 + 4O_2 -> CO_2 + 2CO + 4H_2O

Comment: C3H8 +  4O2 -> CO2 + 2CO + 4H2O (sorry, I thought I posted this earlier, but apparently it didn't go through)

Comment: Ok. Apparently it did go through. Mobile app -_-

Comment: Will the relief valve allow out a mixture of the clean air and the exhaust gases?

Comment: It might be easier to study the volume of exhaust gases in the space rather than the concentration.

Comment: Are you happy with the assumption that the exhaust gases become mixed instantly or do you want to build in a delay while they diffuse into the rest of the space?

Comment: I'm fine with the idea that it becomes mixed instantly, and I'm specifically interested in concentration (ppm). And yes, it will allow a mix of both gasses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, I believe that your ODE for the combustion byproducts volume $C(t)$ is correct -- assuming that the gases don't cool off, which will have an effect on the density. So, we have
\begin{equation}
C'(t) = r - \frac{r}{V} C(t).
\end{equation}
This is *not* equivalent with $C' + C = V$, since
\begin{equation}
 C' + C = r + C - \frac{r}{V} C = r + (1-\frac{r}{V}) C
\end{equation}
which is only equal to $V$ if and only if $r = V$, i.e. if the inflow would fill the volume in exactly one minute.

The solution to your ODE, with initial condition $C(0) = 0$ is given by
\begin{equation}
C(t) = V \left(1-e^{-\frac{r}{V} t}\right).
\end{equation}
As you can see in the plot, the combustion byproducts volume initially increases linearly, and converges to $V$ as $t$ goes to infinity, i.e. it eventually fills the entire chamber.

[image: C as a function of t]

In your case, this doesn't really happen: the inflow stops after a certain volume $F$ (which I assume is less than $V$) is produced. At an inflow rate or $r$ cubic feet per minute, this simply means that after $t_\text{stop} = \frac{F}{r}$ minutes, the inflow stops. At that point in time, the combustion byproducts volume in the chamber is given by
\begin{equation}
 C(t_\text{stop}) = V\left(1-e^{-\frac{F}{V}}\right).
\end{equation}
The combustion byproducts volume as a function of time would then look something like this:

[image: C as a function of t, with finite inflow]

Finally, assuming constant temperature, full mixing and assuming that the combustion byproducts behave as ideal gases, the concentration of carbon monoxide in the chamber after the exhaust event is given by

\begin{equation}
 [\text{CO}] = \frac{2}{7} \left(1-e^{-\frac{F}{V}}\right).
\end{equation}